# How to access Mysql DB variables in Serverspec? can we do it using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, serverspec

I want to access DB variables using Serverspec, but in Serverspec for Windows it is not supported so I am trying using PowerShell but got the following issues

Tried using below powershell command:

```
"cd Program\ Files\\MySQL\\MySQL\ Server\ 5.5\\bin";
"\.\mysql.exe --user=root --password=atmf"
```

But not recognized due to escape characters issue and later if we give the command in double quotes PowerShell prints it as string.

Comment: What "DB variables" do you want to "access"? Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Search Also: "X/Y Problem"

Comment: I want to check this variable particularly "innodb-buffer-pool-size" and "socket" and its value but any other variable will work also.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the commandline client output the variable:

```
$mysql  = "C:\path\to\mysql.exe"

$dbuser = "root"
$dbpass = "..."
$dbname = "database"
$dbvar  = "innodb_buffer_pool_size"

$value = & $mysql -u "$dbuser" -p "$dbpass" -B -D "$dbname" -e "SELECT @@$dbvar"
```